# How to maintain consistancy of Header being on page top throughout all Page Sizes?

Tags: c#, pdf, header, itext

I have set page header (using iTextSharp library) along with margins set only for A4 page size (according to its orientation) -because i have set the document's page size as A4 only- and so it works only for A4 page and shows it on top. Can anybody tell me that how to make this header consistant throughout all Page size whatever user selects? Like it should print the header on the top of each and every predefined page size as it does for A4 because when i select Pagesize.HALFLETTER, Header gets vanished as it goes out of the page boundaries. Any Help?

**UPDATED QUESTION!**

My code is:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.exceptions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace PDFGeneration
{

    public class Events : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        private String header;
        private iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfTemplate total;
        private PdfContentByte cb;
        private PdfTemplate template;


        protected Font footer
        {
            get
            {

                //BaseFont bfArialUniCode = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"fonts\\adobe-arabic-regular-1.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                BaseColor grey = new BaseColor(128, 128, 128);
                Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10.0f, Font.NORMAL, grey);
                //Font font = new Font(bfArialUniCode, 10.0f, Font.NORMAL, grey);
                return font;
            }
        }
        protected Font watermark
        {
            get
            {

                BaseFont bfArialUniCode = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"fonts\\adobe-arabic-regular-1.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                BaseColor grey = new BaseColor(128, 128, 128);
                Font font = new Font(bfArialUniCode, 14.0f, Font.BOLDITALIC, grey);
                return font;
            }
        }
        public override void OnStartPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
        {
            PdfPTable headerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
            headerTbl.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width;

            //Center the table on the page
            headerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph(String.Format("Urdu Word Processor                        Date : {0:dd/MMM/yyyy}                  Page Number : {1}", DateTime.Now, writer.PageNumber), footer);

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(para);


            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.PaddingLeft = 120.0f;
            //cell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
            //add cell to table
            headerTbl.AddCell(cell);
            headerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (document.BottomMargin + 790), writer.DirectContent); 

        }
        public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
        {


            //PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            //PdfPTable tablefooter = new PdfPTable(1);
            ////tablefooter.HeaderRows = 3;
            //tablefooter.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            //float[] widthfooter = new float[] { 1f };
            //tablefooter.SetWidths(widthfooter);

            //tablefooter.SpacingBefore = 100f;

            //PdfPCell headerfooter = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.Format("Urdu Word Processor                 Date : {0:dd/MMM/yyyy}                  Page Number : {1}", DateTime.Now, writer.PageNumber), new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            ////Phrase headerfooter = new Phrase(new Phrase("Urdu Word Processor                            " + "Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy-ss") + "                            " + "Page: " + writer.PageNumber, new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            //headerfooter.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            //headerfooter.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;

            //tablefooter.AddCell(headerfooter);
            ////document.Add(tablefooter);
            //ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            //ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Phrase(new Chunk("بِسْمِ اللّٰهِ الرَّحْمٰنِ الرَّحِيْمِ       ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 18, Font.NORMAL))),
            //                   46, 190, 530, 36, 25, Element.ALIGN_LEFT | Element.ALIGN_TOP);
            //ct.Go();

            // water mark

            //ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContentUnder,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
            //    new Phrase("بِسْمِ اللّٰهِ الرَّحْمٰنِ الرَّحِيْمِ", watermark),
            //    297.5f, 421, ((writer.PageNumber % 2) == 1) ? 45 : -45); // have made a loop so to have multiple orientations.
            ColumnText col = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContentUnder);
            col.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
            col.SetSimpleColumn(220, 810, 569, 36);
            col.AddElement(new Paragraph("بِسْمِ اللّٰهِ الرَّحْمٰنِ الرَّحِيْمِ",watermark));
            col.Go();

        }
        //public void setHeader(String header)
        //{
        //    this.header = header;
        //}
        //public void onOpenDocument(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
        //{
        //    total = writer.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(30,16);
        //}

        //public void onEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document) 
        //{
        //    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        //        try 
        //        {
        //                //table.SetWidths(new int[]{24, 24, 2});
        //                table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] {527.0f,527.0f,527.0f});
        //                //table.LockedWidth = true;
        //                table.DefaultCell.FixedHeight = 20;
        //                table.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
        //                table.AddCell(header);
        //                table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        //                table.AddCell( String.Format("Page:{0} of", writer.PageNumber));
        //               // MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Page:{0} of", writer.PageNumber));
        //                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(total)); 
        //                cell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
        //                table.AddCell(cell);
        //                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1,
        //                34, 803, writer.DirectContent);
        //        }
        //        catch(Exception de) 
        //        {
        //           // MessageBox.Show(de.Message.ToString());
        //        }
        //}
        //public void onCloseDocument(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document) 
        //{
        //    String pageNumber = (writer.PageNumber).ToString();
        //    pageNumber += " of " + (writer.PageNumber).ToString();
        //    iTextSharp.text.pdf.ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent, iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(pageNumber), 580, 10, -90);

        //}



        //override the OnPageEnd event handler to add our footer
        //public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        //{
        //    cb = writer.DirectContent;
        //    template = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
        //}

        //public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        //{
        //    base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

        //    int pageN = writer.PageNumber;
        //    String text = "Page " + pageN.ToString() + " of ";

        //    //float len = this.RunDateFont.BaseFont.GetWidthPoint(text, this.RunDateFont.Size);

        //    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

        //    cb.SetRGBColorFill(100, 100, 100);

        //    cb.BeginText();
        //    //cb.SetFontAndSize(this.RunDateFont.BaseFont, this.RunDateFont.Size);
        //    cb.SetTextMatrix(document.LeftMargin, pageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin));
        //    cb.ShowText(text);

        //    cb.EndText();

        //    cb.AddTemplate(template, document.LeftMargin + 10.0f, pageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin));
        //}

        //public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        //{
        //    base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);
        //    BaseFont bfArialUniCode = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"fonts\\adobe-arabic-regular-1.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        //    template.BeginText();
        //    template.SetFontAndSize(bfArialUniCode, 14.0f);
        //    template.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
        //    template.ShowText("" + (writer.PageNumber - 1));
        //    template.EndText();
        //}



    }// end of class
}
```

This code prints this output onl at the top of A4 page size and it should be because its hard coded values there inside this code to align the text.

### Urdu Word Processor         Date: 17-02-2013           Page Number: 1

```
                         بِسْمِ اللّٰهِ الرَّحْمٰنِ الرَّحِيْمِ
```

How can this be oriented so it should be same for all page sizes?

Comment: When you draw the header, you do it at some coordinated. Replace hard coded coordinates by coordinates calculated from the current page crop or media box.

Comment: Can you show me through any example? I ain't familiar with media or the cropping in this regard? Or you must be talking about getting the page size first and then to set header's orientation accordingly? If so then how to get predefined page size's width and height?

Comment: If you provided the central code you use for header creation, it would be easier to show what to change how.